# $_FILES returns empty when using HTML Form and Dropzone JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, dropzone.js

I have spent way too much time on this and browsed various questions/answers here on stackoverflow.

I am using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to add a basic drag and drop upload feature to our HTML/PHP form.  The drag and drop is working great however when the form is submitted or a file is uploaded the $_FILES returns empty and I cant figure it out.

I checked a [tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php) and no luck, also checked some [Q & A's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940099/php-files-array-is-empty) from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047587/dropzone-form-validation) before [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209584/dropzone-js-files-is-empty) here but nothing has helped.

Here is the form in its simplest form:

```
<form action="<? echo BASE_URL; ?>/process-uploads.php" method="POST" class="form-signin" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="upload_container dropzone">Drag & drop file here or

                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="ad" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div><!--fileUpload btn btn-primary-->

        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>

                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-forward" style="background:#00a85a;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Step" />
            </form>
```

The JS is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
    url: "<? echo BASE_URL; ?>/process-uploads.php/",
    paramName: "ad",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    //maxFiles: 1,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    //uploadMultiple: false,
    acceptedFiles: "image/png",
    dictInvalidFileType: "This file type is not supported.",

});
</script>
```

And process-upload.php just checks to see if anything was sent, but returning empty:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    echo 'We have a file';

    if($_FILES['ad']) {
        echo 'We grabbed the ad<br />';

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($_FILES);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. For reference I already checked enyo's tutorial for [combining a form with dropzone and php](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone)

Comment: can you try to give a class 'dropzone' to your form too ?

Comment: as per http://www.dropzonejs.com/ you should give 'dropzone' class to your <form> tag. let me know if it solves your issue

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today getting no response, no error whatsoever when uploading a file and search through all SO questions, i read your code couple of time but no solution.
i later found out that `post_max_size = 8M` is set too small, large files cannot be uploaded. Make sure you set `post_max_size` large enough, so kindly create/add this to your .htaccess file, i needed to upload a file of 2gb

```
php_value upload_max_filesize    2047M
php_value post_max_size          2047M
php_value max_execution_time     10800
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name` to your field:

```
<input type="file" name="ad" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I had that in there originally but after troubleshooting I removed it and put it back, that wasnt the issue though.

Answer (score -2):

I think you took reference of this article...
[Dropzone Demo](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php)

Can you please add class 'dropzone' to your form like following and try

```
<form action="<? echo BASE_URL; ?>/process-uploads.php" method="POST" class="dropzone form-signin" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```